# Does Sovryn really not allow you to use it if you use Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, decentralization, decentralized-exchanges

https://live.sovryn.app/

This is apparently what Sovryn consists of. Not a downloadable application, but a website. It's very confusing, and so is its FAQ.

When I click the "Engage Wallet" button, it pops up a choice between:

1. "Browser Wallet".
2. "Mobile Wallet".
3. "Hardware Wallet" (disabled/greyed out).

Where is the "desktop wallet"? How do I use Bitcoin Core with this thing? Why would it support only "browser wallets"? I didn't even know that such a thing existed.

I keep hearing all these fantastic claims, but then when I try to actually use it, it's just... vapor? Fluff? Or am I once again missing something that you all understand?

Comment: This question could be improved by phrasing the query as an open-ended question such as e.g. "How can I use Sovryn if I use Bitcoin Core as my wallet?".

Answer (score 1):

Sovryn is built on the Rootstock Bitcoin-sidechain. It follows that you must run software that interacts with the Rootstock sidechain in order to use Sovryn. Bitcoin Core only interacts with Bitcoin's blockchain and is not aware of the Rootstock sidechain.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the "desktop wallet"? How do I use Bitcoin Core with this thing? Why would it support only "browser wallets"? I didn't even know that such a thing existed.

Bitcoin Core is mainly a Bitcoin full node implementation. It has wallet as well which can be used but there are so many other open source wallets available to be used in different things depending on user, projects etc. You don't need to use just bitcoin core wallet for using bitcoin.

Few other open source bitcoin wallets: https://bitcoinwallet.guide

Few wallets that involve browser extensions for bitcoin or bitcoin sidechains:

https://liquality.io

https://vulpem.com/marina.html

Mobile wallet and Hardware wallet(assuming it's a WIP) should help the users who don't want to use browser extension wallets in the website mentioned in question

Comment: Um... Sure... but I use Bitcoin Core and wouldn't trust any other wallet. Why is that not allowed?

Comment: Bitcoin Core is open source. Maybe open a pull request and add features that you need and others agree to it. Or contact the support for website mentioned in question if they help users that use only bitcoin core wallet.

Comment: There are few things that can be done on Sovryn from any wallet. Quoting from one of their emails: `Staking can be done with either BTC or RBTC so you do not need to convert RBTC in advance. The reservation system will provide you with a unique Bitcoin address if you wish to stake BTC. You should be able to transfer BTC to this address from almost any Bitcoin wallet.`

Comment: For others you can write code because it's open source: https://github.com/DistributedCollective or contact support in telegram or discord for features that you want to add in the project